# как выполнить функцию js после асинхронной загрузки библиотеки

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

На сайте, в блоке `head`, у всех подключаемых скриптов стоит async, кроме двух:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/java/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/java/cusel-min-2.3.1.js"></script>
```

Где-то в body вызывается функция `cuSel`, которая находит на странице нужный `<select>` и превращает его в кучу дивов (для "красоты").

```
var params = {
changedEl: ".lineForm select",
visRows: 18,
scrollArrows: true
}
cuSel(params);
```

Для вызова нужно, чтобы `cusel-min-2.3.1.js` был уже загружен. Сама библиотека `cusel-min-2.3.1.js` использует `jquery-1.5.2.min.js`, то есть он должен быть загружен первым, выходит.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то выйти из ситуации и организовать код так, чтобы все это загружалось асинхронно и вызов `cuSel(params)` происходил после загрузки этих двух библиотек? (я пытался смотреть соседние темы но ответа не нашел)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подвязать вызов функции на событие `window.onload`, оно триггерится после того, как все скрипты будут загружены.

Comment: Такой вариант может визуально, не очень смотреться. Запускаемая функция модифицирует 1 тег, в кучу других. Но это топикстартеру решать)

Comment: Спасибо, частично помогло! Поставил `async` для `cusel-min-2.3.1.js` и вызов отнес в window.onload. Работает идеально, правда, как и сказал @Дмытрык, сначала видно плохой селект, потом нормальный, но это не критично (лишь бы поисковикам нравилось). А вот если задать 'async' для `jquery-1.5.2.min.js`, то все работает не совсем корректно. jquery видать нужен для cusel, и он (cusel) как-то не до конца загружается.

Comment: В итоге просто переписал селект вручную и удалил нахрен эту библиотеку cusel.